# OpenVPN setup: Problems connecting due to UDP packet overflow

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, firewall, openvpn, sonicwall

I'm attempting to setup an OpenVPN server on a Win2k3 server running behind a sonicwall. To eliminate config issues with the firwall, I'm trying to connect to the server from another PC on the same internal subnet. I've turned off the firewall on both server and client boxes just to eliminate that as the culprit. When I try to connect here is the log output:

```
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 OpenVPN 2.2.0 Win32-MSVC++ [SSL] [LZO2] built on Apr 26 2011
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 LZO compression initialized
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '41690919'
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '530fdded'
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 UDPv4 link remote: 192.168.2.3:1194
Mon May 09 14:37:56 2011 read UDPv4: Connection reset by peer (WSAECONNRESET) (code=10054)
```

I've read that this error indicates that the client is sending packets faster than the server can read them. UDP requires the app do it's own flow control and I can't find anything in the docs to configure this kind of control. I have also tried connection from a remote site and have the same problem.

I can share my config files if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the OpenVPN server node logs to debug this. The client-side logs might be misleading as things like timeouts or connection resets are unspecific error conditions caused by a particular configuration problem.